# Package listed with pip but cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, setup.py

I am writing my own package for a test with `setup.py`. I tried to install it on my own computer with `python3 setup.py install`, and there was no error. I checked with `pip3 list` and found it there,

```
steplib         0.1.0
```

However, when I tried importing it in a python interpreter, I could not,

```
>>> import steplib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'steplib'
```

Using `help('modules')` confirmed this as it was not shown in the list.
Am I doing anything wrong? Do I have to register it first before using it?

### edit

---

My `site packages` contains `steplib-0.1.0-py3.7.egg-info`. It does not have any sub-packages (it is a test package):

steplib

__init__.py

steplib.py

setup.py

Answer (score 1):

Ideally module should go into your site packages. Do you see it there?

If its there then check your package path. You package may be steplib, but have you checked if you are importing right package and module there. For example within your steplib folder you might have additional package and module within it. Say package is X and module is Y. Then you can import it as below.

```
from X import Y
```

Make sure you have **init**.py in your package to qualify that as a package.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the package in the python directory under Lib?